# Why does my female cat stomach area hang so low?

Tags: cats, weight

When she's walking around I can see her belly hanging low. She has never gotten pregnant before. Does she just need to lose weight?

She is also spayed and is a one-and-a-half year old house cat, if that helps.

Comment: It's possible it's because she was spayed. My female cat has had the same since she got spayed. It does not have to related to being overweight. The belly area loses it's 'strenght' after getting spayed and it's possible it starts hanging.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the fact that the cat got spayed. I have a female cat who hasn't been fixed, she's 6 months old and has a saggy little belly. She isn't overweight at all she's really small and in healthy shape, it's just a natural part of the cat's anatomy and developes as the cat matures.

Comment: My kitty is 18 and has always been slender.Her "pouch"started being apparent about 5 years ago.It's super soft and almost touching the floor now.There is no weight to lose,so maybe it will eventually drag which would be very indignant for her.I see a huge similarity between women's breasts and the cat's "apron".It doesn't matter if they had kittens or babies to lose shape and start sagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loose, hanging skin on a cat's belly is simply a natural part of a cat's anatomy, sometimes called the apron, or as in the following article, the primordial pouch.  This is more prominent on some cats than others, and can become more obvious in cats as they age or gain or lose weight.  Getting spayed or neutered does not cause your cat to gain an apron, but it may make it more obvious due to related changes in weight.

http://pawesomecats.com/2013/11/19/why-does-my-cat-have-a-flabby-tummy/

Comment: Both my boy and girl tabbies have aprons. My half- Siamese girl had less of one. I think this is just a matter of individual body shape. Unless the vet expresses concern, I really don't think it's meaningful.